# Need help -string mapping in TCL

Tags: tcl

How to perform string mapping for a value stored in a variable? 
Example:
I have my output in a variable say "a".

```
set a "a.b12.d4" (its unknown)
```

Is it possible to use string map to map contents of  $a as "\t" in another variable say b?

like,

```
    set c [string map {"contents of $a" "\t"}$b]
```

{I know $a cannot be used here. Is there a way to subtitute contents of $a here in string mapping?}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible if you do not use curly braces as they prevent substitution:

```
set a "a.b12.d4"
set b "$a.123"
puts [string map [list $a \t] $b]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I edited my question now as I framed it wrongly. Kindly respond to the edited version

Comment: probably safer to use `[list $a \t]` instead of a double quoted string.

Comment: @glenn Not merely “probably”…